# Making a Radio button and use it in any component

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to use a Radio button and use it in different component with different styling without rewriting html and css. and also I want them to change their style when I toggle each

firstly I made the radio button as a component in a separate component using html and some css

```
<div class="list-item" (click)="check()">
  <span class="list-item-text">
    {{data.value}}
  </span>
  <div class="inputs">
    <span class="box">
      <span class="inner-box" [class.fill]="fill"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and used ts to make the toggle functions

```
export class ProductAllFilterComponent implements OnInit {
public Categories =[];

  constructor(
    private categoryService:CategoryService,
    private _router:Router) { 
      this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe((response:any)=>{
        this.Categories = response.data;
      });
  }
active = 1;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  goToLink(link) {
    this._router.navigate([link])
  }
  // route back to home

  activeSection(index) {
    this.active = index;
  }
}
```

How can I make this into and reusable component and add different style to it without changing its style in all other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to add @Input() and ngStyle to your component.
For example il you want your button to be red at some point you could use in the TS:

```
@Input() color: string;
defaultColor: //your default color
```

and in the HTML:

```
<span class="box" [ngStyle]="{'background: color ? color : defaultColor'}"> ...
```

Then you have to call your component in another component using it's selector like:

```
<app-custom-checkbox color="#ff0000"></app-custom-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot does ng-content work here too? or its not a good approach here

Comment: I don't think this woulb be a good solution because you would have to fill your ng-content with the same type of data so you would loose the genericity of your checkbox component